# Recorrer un array con un campo JSON

Tags: vue.js

Buenas noches en la siguiente imagen se ve una duda que tengo en algo que estoy haciendo toda ayuda es bienvenida recibida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta ahora???

Comment: ¿Y por qué es una imagen? Escribe la duda en texto y pon el código que tienes

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el componente carrousel de bootstrap:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/)

En tu caso quedaría algo como:

```js
var data = [{
  nombre: 'noticia1',
  fotos: [{id:0,foto:'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg'},{id:1, foto:'https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/549585-istock-909106260.jpg?itok=ds7LqH1N&resize=1100x1100'}]
  },
  {
  nombre: 'noticia2',
  fotos: [{id:3,foto:'https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/549585-istock-909106260.jpg?itok=ds7LqH1N&resize=1100x1100'},{id:4,foto:'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg'}]
  }
];

var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    noticias: data,
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body >
  <div id="app">

  <div v-for="(noticia,idex) in noticias" id="fotos">
    <div v-bind:id="'carouselExampleControls' + idex" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div v-for="(foto,idx) in noticia.fotos" class="carousel-item" :class="{ active: idx==0 }">
          <img class="d-block w-100" v-bind:src="foto.foto" v-bind:alt="noticia.nombre">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" v-bind:href="'#carouselExampleControls' + idex"  role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" v-bind:href="'#carouselExampleControls' + idex"  role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Acá ves que creo un div por cada noticia y por cada noticia creamos un carousel con las fotos que vienen siendo varios "carousel-item", en tu caso sería crear un tr por cada noticia y dentro del td el carousel, cuidado con los id de los controles de avanzar y retrocedes, ya que concateno el indice del array para hacerlos unicos en el documento.

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Hola @zerocool, viendo tu reputación ya deberías saber que no es buena práctica responder preguntas que no demuestran trabajo o investigación previa. Por favor, lee [answer] para ver en qué casos se debe poner una respuesta y en cuales no.

Comment: Hola @zerocool gracias por tu aporte me a ayudado mucho lo único es que yo tengo el campo fotos en formato JSON entonces al recorrerlo me lo toma como string y el for recorre el tamaño de lo que está en el campo es decir, cuando declaró V-for="foto un noticia.fotos" no comprende que es un arrays sino string, no sé si hay una forma de convertirlo en arrays ahí mismo

Comment: hola, si debes leer sobre JSON.parse(). Saludos.

Comment: Si eso lo entiendo lo que no se es como hacerlo por cada noticia no se en que parte convertir al formato json, no sé si me puedas decir cómo lo puedo realizarlo te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: @zerocool hay posibilidad de convertir en el formato JSON cada vez que recorro una noticia ?

Comment: Hola, eso tienes que hacerlo cuando estes creando el array con la data, o si ya lo obtienes hecho vas a tener que procesarlo primero y luego es que se lo mandas al vue. Porque en el front no creo que vue te deje hacer eso, habría que leer la documentación igual a ver.